# How to include VM arguments into JAR file?

Tags: eclipse, jar, splash-screen

I have an application that is showing splash screen when loading it. It all works perfectly in Eclipse environment, but when I try to export it as (Runnable) JAR file, it does not. I guess it has a problem to include VM arguments (in this case a path to the splash screen's image). I was trying to run it in the command line, just like:

```
java -jar App.jar
```

and I got an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Splash Screen not set!
        at org.cnstar.util.SplashManager.<init>(SplashManager.java:32)
        at org.cnstar.wiki.app.GreatPlaces$1.run(GreatPlaces.java:289)
```

So my question is: is there a way how to include VM arguments in JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the splash screen in the `MANIFEST` file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: <class name>
SplashScreen-Image: <image name>
```

See [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for reference.

Comment: I have created such MANIFEST file and I wanted to add it in a process of creating JAR, however, it is throwing an error, saying "JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  invalid header field name: ï»¿Manifest-Version
  invalid header field name: ï»¿Manifest-Version
 "

Comment: @MichalB Your MANIFEST is wrong. Remove the `ï»¿` from the beginning which is the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark).